# Why allow Pycharm to update or delete other applications?

Tags: pycharm

Received a banner notification saying Pycharm tried to update/delete other applications but was blocked. I clicked on it and I was taken to this page
[image]

What is the point of allowing Pycharms to update or delete applications? And how much power is this giving Pycharm? Could it delete any application off my laptop?